# using iodbc in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to connect to FileMaker through a Rust application (don't ask me why...) - and I run into the wall of the FM ODBC driver being built against iodbc and not unixodbc, but all the ODBC crates I find are using unixodbc.

I'm not too familiar with the lower level stuff around cargo, so I have no idea if and how I can make the Rust odbc crates link against iodbc instead of unixodbc. I asked Google but came up empty.

Can I force cargo to link against a specific library (both unixodbc and iodbc are present on the system, but unixodbc seems to be always picked by default) ?

Comment: I do believe this is possible if you use `cargo rustc` and manually link iodbc. I, however am not knowledgeable enough to know how to do that, although using verbose output might give you an idea.

Comment: @Aiden4 might try that if I find no other solution. Though I'm not even sure WHICH of the three or four odbc packages is the one that is actually linked to the C library. :-/

Comment: If it is statically linked, you can probably tell which one does the linking by looking at the dependencies of the odbc crates in the cargo.lock. Also, if that doesn't work, look for the crate with `extern "C"` functions.

Answer (score 2):

Disclosure: I am the owner of the `odbc-api` and `odbc-sys` crate.

You can use iodbc from Rust, but you must enable the `iodbc` feature flag in your `Cargo.toml`.

```
[dependencies]
odbc-api = { version = "0.40.1", features = ["iodbc"] }
```

Setting this flag achieves three things:

### Your applications links against `libiodbc.so` rather than `libodbc.so`.

Without that you you would get a linker error indicating that `-lodbc` is not found.

### Your application uses the 3.5 standard of ODBC.

... and declares the ODBC version to be 3.0.

iODBC currently only supports version 3.5.
If your application would use ODBC 3.8 it would fail to create an ODBC Environment. The iodbc driver manager does not return any error in this case. It just fails.

### Your application uses narrow (Utf-8) function calls.

iodbc just does not seem to work with Utf-16. This is anecdotical knowledge, though. It might also have been an issue with the data source.

Without this you could not create an ODBC Connection. Status codes in error messages are truncated (less than five letters).

`odbc-api` will assume your system has a local using utf-8 encoding. If not expect panics, in case special characters appear in queries or connection strings.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. I'll give it a spin though right now it's low priority because of a deadline and I had to implement it using JDBC and java instead of keep the deadline. But I'd much rather have this in Rust than in Java.

Comment: Don't worry too much. I only had to add for lines to `odbc-sys` and I hope it is also to some use to other people. Should you give it a spin, you are likely to be the first one to use that driver manager with the Rust bindings, which means you would charter some unknown territory. So do not hesitate to raise an issue on GitHub should you run into trouble.